# How to make topic subscription in IBM MQ AMQP unmodifiable or unalterable by client program?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, amqp, jms-topic

Software Used : IBM MQ 8.0.0.5 and Java MQ client

We have durable IBM MQ subscriber connecting to topic using **AMQP** channel. Subscriber is created offline using **runmqsc** commands and has expiry **UNLIMITED**. But whenever our client is up and subscription is started or resumed, **EXPIRY** of subscription is altered to 0. What changes we can make so subscription will not be altered by client program and hence will be durable?

Does it have anything specific attributes or permission we can use while creating subscriber so it will be unalterable by MQ client(Client will be any client like .NET client or C++ Client or Java client)?

Note : We are using **Apache QPID** client for JNDI and JMS as Java MQ client.

Thanks,
Sagii

Comment: Matt from IBM already answered this, it is not possible with MQ V8.

Comment: Since you are using JMS why not just directly use IBM MQ classes for JMS, these would not have this issue you face even at versions before 9.2.  Is there a specific driver to use Apache QPID JMS (via AMQP protocol) to access IBM MQ?

Comment: @JoshMc ... we are using AMQP channels for which they have mentioned apache QPID library or IBM MQ light library

Comment: v8.0.0.5 is very old by any standard, it is out of support from IBM as of April 30 2020 (almost 5.5 months ago).  8.0.0.5 was released over 4 years ago (May 25 2016), the most recent (likely last) fixpack is 8.0.0.15 released June 9th 2020.  This version of MQ does not support the Apache QPID connecting and having durable subscribers as mentioned by Matt.

Comment: Given the background that you are connecting to a MQ queue manager that does not support durable AMQP apache QPID durable subscribers, what I'm asking is why do you NEED to use apache QPID?  You could instead directly use the "IBM MQ classes for JMS" to connect to MQ and subscribe and you would not have the issues you have with apache QPID.  Is there a reason you MUST use apache QPID 
 connecting to an AMQP channel over the IBM provided JMS libraries connecting to a SVRCONN channel?

Comment: Matt's answer to you is likely one of the best as he is one of the main developers of the IBM MQ AMQP functionality, I don't understand why you would post a second question asking the same thing that has already been answered.

Comment: @JoshMc .. I thought this is different issue so should have different question ... anyways ... We are using apache qpid because we are having AMQP channels and for connecting them only two options we could see were using IBM mqlight or apache QPID ... Here, I would like to know can we use "IBM MQ classes for JMS" for connecting to AMQP channels ?

Comment: You wouldn't use "IBM MQ classes for JMS" for connecting to AMQP channels, you would use "IBM MQ classes for JMS" for connecting to SVRCONN channels.  What is the reason you must use AMQP channels?

Comment: @JoshMc As our client is having provision for using AMQP, we are using AMQP and they will use AMQP with .NET Core ...We are using QPID for testing purposes..so does .NET Core client has any facility to set EXPIRY to unlimited while creating durable subscription?

Comment: My answer to your original question has a link to a article discussing how to do it with .NET, have you looked at that article I linked to?

Comment: Yes .. I went through it ... I had missed the point ... Thanks for pin pointing

Comment: I think to be fair, Matt's answer to your other question is the right answer related to QPID and should be accepted.  If you edit this question to specifically ask about .NET AMQP I can delete my answer the other question and move it over here as it would be a good answer to your .NET question.  Also I do want to stress that you should try to stay up to day with the latest fixpack of the version you are running and not get out of support, this is even more of a requirement when you have external connections into your queue manager, you surely want the latest security patches that are included.